# Remove WooCommerce metaboxes on product edit page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want remove some metaboxes from the product edit page.
The code that I use is settled in functions.php

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() { 
    remove_meta_box( 'postexcerpt', 'product', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-product_tag', 'product', 'side' );
    remove_meta_box( 'postcustom', 'product', 'normal');
}, 90);
```

The metaboxes **postexcerpt** and **tagsdiv-product_tag** are removed from the page but the **postcustom** metabox is still there. I tried also a higher prioritynumber but this fixed not the issue.

Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Try the built-in option to enable and disable meta boxes